# How to pass data from an activity to another activity and then to another activity on Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, onclick, onitemclicklistener

I managed to pass data from a list activity to another activity. However, from the 2nd activity to the 3rd, I doubt I could pass the same data as the app crashes when it goes to the 3rd. Is it not possible to send the same data starting from the 1st activity or is there something wrong along the lines?

This is the 1st Activity

```
ListView lv = getListView();

    // on selecting single product
    // launching Edit Shops Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String sid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShopPage.class);
            // sending sid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_SID, sid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

This is the 2nd activity:

```
        // getting shop details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting shop id (sid) from intent
        sid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_SID);

editButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sid = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent e = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditShopPage.class);
            // sending sid to next activity
            e.putExtra(TAG_SID, sid);
            startActivity (e);
            }
    });
```

And this is the 3rd activity :

```
    // getting shop details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting shop id (sid) from intent
    sid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_SID);
```

The 1st activity comes from a ListView activity where the data passes by onItemClickListener. Then the 2nd activity receives but passes to the next with onClick (a Button). After this the app just stopped running.

Comment: Is there an exception in LogCat view? Please show it to us.

Comment: Is it the one that says FATAL EXCEPTION? If it is then LogCat shows this :
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.iukl.iuklfoodapp.ShopPage$3.onClick(ShopPage.java:135)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4367)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17984)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)

Comment: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I am sorry if this is not it as I am new to this

Comment: A NullPointerException seems to be happening at ShopPage.java line 135, what's the code in this line?

Comment: sid = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sid)).getText().toString();

Perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: Most likely, v.findViewById(R.id.sid)) is returning null. Put a breakpoint in this line, run in debug mode and inspect this line. Check which one is throwing an NPE.

Comment: sorry I don't understand the term breakpoint and NPE. Am I supposed to toggle breakpoint on this line?

Comment: i removed that line and the data manage to pass through. thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In second Activity:**
Remove below code because you already have sid from first Activity.

```
sid = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sid)).getText()
                .toString();
```

Add `sid` from `i.getStringExtra(TAG_SID);` in your Intent which you already did it. If your IDE shows anything make `sid` variable final or declare it as Activity member variable.

Hope it will help.

Comment: yup. this was the problem. I just noticed it earlier. thanks for answering though.

Answer (score 0):

Without the logs I can't see where the error comes from. Most of the time, when I have to pass a simple variable such as a String from one activity to another I'm using this code. I hope it can helps.

First Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle bundleF = new Bundle();
bundleF.putString("type", NOTIF);               
intent.putExtras(bundleF);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity:

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("type")
```

Comment: I have included the logs at the comment of my question. I also tried your solution but it did not worked. However, this time it opened a glimpse of the next screen for a short while. Perhaps I have something else which is wrong?